# Unable to add another column in an on screen keyboard Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard

Currently I am creating a phone simulator using Tkinter. I just need an on screen keyboard in the format of:

*! q w e r t y u i o p*

*tab  a s d f g h j k l*

*caps z x c v b n m  , . /*

Till now, I have succeeded.

But I want to add another column consisting of numbers.

However, it is not happening. The numbers are coming in the third row.

Here's my program:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("366x650")

textBox = Text(root, width=50, height=30,
               wrap=WORD)

textBox.place(x=5, y=200)
textBox.focus_set()

buttons = [
    '!', 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '←',
    'Tab', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', '[', ']',
    'Shift', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', '/', '?',
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', ':', ";",
    ' Space '
]

varRow = 4
varCol = 0

shift_on = False
letter_buttons = []


def is_letter(s):
    return len(s) == 1 and 'a' <= s <= 'z'


def buttonClick(user_input):
    global shift_on

    if user_input == 'Shift':
        shift_on = not shift_on
        for btn in letter_buttons:
            text = btn['text']
            btn['text'] = text.upper() if shift_on else text.lower()
    else:
        if user_input == ' Space ':
            textBox.insert(INSERT, ' ')
        elif user_input == 'Tab':
            textBox.insert(INSERT, '    ')
        elif user_input == '←':
            backspace()
        else:
            if is_letter(user_input):
                user_input = user_input.upper() if shift_on else user_input.lower()
            textBox.insert(INSERT, user_input)


def backspace():
    textBox.delete('insert-1chars', INSERT)


for button in buttons:
    cmd = lambda x=button: buttonClick(x)

    if button != ' Space ':
        btn = Button(root, text=button, width=3,
                     command=cmd)
        btn.grid(row=varRow, column=varCol)
        if is_letter(button):
            letter_buttons.append(btn)

    if button == ' Space ':
        Button(root, text=button, command=cmd).grid(row=6, columnspan=16)
    varCol += 1

    if varCol > 11 and varRow == 4:
        varCol = 0
        varRow += 1

    if varCol > 11 and varRow == 5:
        varCol = 0
        varRow += 1

root.mainloop()
```

I would be very grateful to anyone who helps :)

Comment: maybe instead of two `if`s use one like this: `if varCol > 11 and varRow >=4:` at least that solved it for me in the sense that numbers appeared. I guess it is also possible to just add another `if` like this: `if varCol > 11 and varRow == 6` but it would be much more compact to use just one like mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

It is because when `varRow` is 6, the two `if` statements will be evaluated as `False`, so `varRow` will not be changed anymore.  So the two rows before `' Space '` will be put at the same row 6.

Also you have hard-coded `grid(row=6, ...)` for the `' Space '` will also put at row 6.

You should have only one `if` statement without checking `varRow`:

```py
for button in buttons:
    cmd = lambda x=button: buttonClick(x)

    if button != ' Space ':
        btn = Button(root, text=button, width=3, command=cmd)
        btn.grid(row=varRow, column=varCol)
        if is_letter(button):
            letter_buttons.append(btn)
    else:
        Button(root, text=button, command=cmd).grid(row=varRow, columnspan=12) # use varRow instead of 6

    varCol += 1
    if varCol > 11:
        varCol = 0
        varRow += 1
```

Note that `row=varRow` is used instead of `row=6` in `.grid(...)` for `' Space '`.

---

Actually you can calculate `varRow` and `varCol` using the index of the key:

```py
COLS = 12
for i, button in enumerate(buttons):
    cmd = lambda x=button: buttonClick(x)
    varRow, varCol = i//COLS+4, i%COLS

    if button != ' Space ':
        btn = Button(root, text=button, width=3, command=cmd)
        btn.grid(row=varRow, column=varCol)
        if is_letter(button):
            letter_buttons.append(btn)
    else:
        Button(root, text=button, command=cmd).grid(row=varRow, columnspan=COLS)
```